is there a way to filter through a list of data in firebase database

From userlocation how do I filter users from the same city using firebase database flutter. I've checked google and the documentation nothing has worked and its driving me crazy. with the documentation using orderByChild('city') and .equalTo('...') I could not get any data.
I already tried
DatabaseReference firebaseDataBaseTest(FirebaseDatabase db, [String? ref]) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    db.useDatabaseEmulator('localhost', 9000);
    return db.ref(ref);
  }
  return db.ref(ref);
}

final snapshot = await firebaseDataBaseTest(_db)
     .child('userLocation')
          .orderByChild('city')
          .equalTo('city')
          .get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        print('---------------->${snapshot.value}');
        return;
      }

which gives me nothing but when I try to get the stored data without filtering like the below
final snapshot = await firebaseDataBaseTest(_db)
     .child('userLocation').get();
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        print('---------------->${snapshot.value}');
        return;
      }


I get the below data from the database
---------------->{4b29d31c-fb01-4bdd-88a9-b2252f151d6f: {city: ikj, companyName: , countryOrRegion: ng, firstAddress: call roads, firstName: ace, id: 4b29d31c-fb01-4bdd-88a9-b2252f151d6f, isDefaultAddress: true, lastName: ace, phoneNumber: 22343, postalOrZipCode: , secondAddress: , stateOrProvince: lg, uid: 6QGzyRuQHF8FWekdj7XoKEdtu0fC}, c8d05ca2-727d-4051-bc77-e12d87a6b83f: {city: city, companyName: , countryOrRegion: reg, firstAddress: second address, firstName: ace , id: c8d05ca2-727d-4051-bc77-e12d87a6b83f, isDefaultAddress: false, lastName: 2, phoneNumber: 121345, postalOrZipCode: , secondAddress: , stateOrProvince: prov, uid: 6QGzyRuQHF8FWekdj7XoKEdtu0fC}}

All i want is to filter a particular field like uid or city and get a list of data that has that uid or city in common.

Please edit the question to show the specific code that you did try, and explain what it did that was different than what you expected.  Without that, you might get an answer that just tells you to do exactly what you already tried.  We need to see what you might have done wrong the first time.

Querying for orderByChild('city').equalTo('city') on userLocation is the right query to select this node, so likely the problem is in how you implemented it. As Doug said, please add the code for a minimal repro to your question (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Please edit your question and add the information Doug and Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

already edited it @AlexMamo

You're using .orderByChild('city') .equalTo('city') but I added the result city: ikj. I'm not sure I understand. Can you please explain?

@AlexMamo if you look at the result there are two data of Map<String, dynamic> returned one with ikj and one with city i didn't want to add the entire result. the result i was expecting after filtering is to get a list of data in which city ('key') is equal to city ('value').

Did you try to query the exact same data online?

Yes I did same result. Don't worry I already switched to firestore and everything works
